# Decompose Specific Links When Scraping Data (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is a section of HTML code I am currently scraping.

```
<div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="LiveBoard1_LiveBoard1_litGamesPanel">
    <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2016&month=0&season1=2016&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=p2018-04-20">
        Today's Probable Starters and Lineups Leaderboard
    </a>
</div>
```

Throughout the code, I need to figure out a way to scrape all the links in this div class with the exception of the one posted above. Does anyone know how to decompose one specific link within a specific div class but still scrape the remaining links? With regards to this specific link, the beginning ("leaders.aspx") of the link is different than the links I am currently targeting. Below is a sample of my current code.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/livescoreboard.aspx?date=2018-04-18')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#Remove Unwanted Links
[link.decompose() for link in soup.find_all(class_='lineup')]
[yesterday.decompose() for yesterday in soup.find_all('td',attrs= 
{'colspan':'2'})]


team_name_list=soup.find(class_='RadAjaxPanel')
team_name_list_items=team_name_list.find_all('a')


for team_name in team_name_list_items:
  teams=team_name.contents[0]
  print(teams)

winprob_list=soup.find(class_='RadAjaxPanel')
winprob_list_items=winprob_list.find_all('td',attrs={'style':'border:1px 
solid black;'})

for winprob in winprob_list_items:
  winprobperc=winprob.contents[0]
  print(winprobperc)
```

To summarize, I just need to remove the "Today's Probable Starters and Lineups Leaderboard" link that was posted in the first code block. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) with [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors): `soup.select_one('.RadAjaxPanel > center > a').decompose()`

Comment: That worked! Thanks Jatimir!

Comment: I added it as an answer, you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) with [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one('.RadAjaxPanel > center > a').decompose()
```